# Encoding issue when click to view source on new tab on Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel

I have encoding issue on my project.When i look to inspect element on current page everything is right. When I open page source on new tab I get encoding problem. http://ippos.org/articles/epokos

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you show your blade file where you're setting the meta data?

Comment: The issue not on meta data. The same issue on content too.
http://prntscr.com/m678nh

Comment: Ok, well can you show your code for one of the places it's happening? I only mentioned the meta data as it's what you've shown in your question.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/m6820p page sources.
http://prntscr.com/m682b0 page interface
http://prntscr.com/m682lr page source on inspect element
http://prntscr.com/m6830e page source on new tab.

Comment: Use `{!! !!}` instead of `{{ }}`. Also, in future can you add your actual code to your question instead of the images in the comments :)

Comment: For articles->content i am using { !!  !!} {!! $article->content !!} but same problem. Thanks for your advice too :)

Comment: Can you confirm that it's not stored that way in the database?

Comment: Datas stored in the database .